# Mac terminal check if screen sharing is enabled

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-high-sierra

I am right now working on a method to track whether screen sharing is enabled or disabled. I have tried two methods so far, checking for the existence of the launch file with

```
[[ -f /etc/com.apple.screensharing.agent.launchd ]] && echo 'enabled' || echo 'disabled'
```

I have also tried a read command checking the boolean value of the disabled variable using the following.

```
sudo defaults read /var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist com.apple.screensharing -dict Disabled -bool false
```

Is there something I'm missing or perhaps a method I haven't tried yet?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Those options didn't work for me either, I used
`sudo launchctl list com.apple.screensharing` which will succeed if it's running, hence enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Both commands did work successfully for me (macOS Monterey):

```bash
$ netstat -a tcp --listening | grep -Ei "rfb.*listen"
```

Or, better (instant):

```bash
$ nmap -p 5900 localhost
```

No need to use `sudo` in both cases.